# How to Recover/Retrieve Deleted Project in netbeans 8.2?

Tags: netbeans, editor, netbeans-8.2

First time, When I was trying to delete my project I did `Rightclick>project_name>deleteproject` then an alert window with a checkbox 'Delete Source folder too' appeared then I unchecked it after that my project was only deleted from netbeans but for the second time when I click on 'delete project' option in the popup window there is no checkbox with 'Delete source folder too' doesn't appeared so I thought it will not going to delete the source folder because as I already selected "don't delete" option while first time I deleted my project, but my guess was wrong the project was deleted from the source path also. My installed netbeans has only with php, javascript & HTML packages. Netbeans is very dangerous IDE I think. Please can anyone tell me how to recover my project?

**Note: I searched for the same topic I found few solutions but they were not working though its because of netbeans version I think.**

Answer (score -1):

Go to the file viewer, and go to documents, then click on netbeansprojects and they should be there